# Why does [...Array(3)] gives a different result than Array(3).map(el => undefined)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

In javascript, when creating a new Array of length 3, I cannot seem to wrap my head around why this works:

```
[...Array(3)] // [undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

But this won't work:

```
Array(3).map(e => undefined) // [ , , ]
```

As I understood correctly here, `Array(3)` will return an array with 3 empty slots, which is not the same as  `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`, but why can you not iterate over them with `map` but the spread operator can?

Comment: [].map() skips empty slots, look at a polyfill's source for details.

Comment: Ok! thanks, so the spread operator does not skip empty slots?

Comment: spread doesn't skip empty (uninitialized) elements.